# Using Integration account for non EDI/X12 partners

Tags: azure-logic-apps

We are trying to build a BizTalk-like solution using Azure logic apps where we trade documents with many trading partners receive messages in HL7 health care format.  Right now we have a logic app that receives documents from one of several connectors and puts them in a service bus queue.  Then we have a second logic app that processes those messages and puts them in a topic.

Then, without using an integration account, we have a logic app per trading partner that subscribes to that topic with a filter that is looking for a message with their routing ID but this approach requires a logic app per trading partner along with a subscription filter.

It seems like using an integration would be a better approach but everything I've read indicates that this type of account requires partners to use EDI/X12 format to get the routing capability. Since the format that we are sending is HL7, is it still possible (preferable) to use an integration account to manage non-EDI/X12 partners or is the current approach of creating a logic app per trading partner the recommended way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, there is no direct HL7 support in Azure or Integration Accounts specifically.  If you're using an Xml version of HL7, this isn't really a problem.

As for routing, Integration Accounts don't really 'route' EDI either.  Your app still have to resolve the Endpoint somehow.  An IA can help by giving a place to store the target URL though.  I haven't yet tried to access the Partner Metadata yet which would be great to store endpoint details :(sorry).

Otherwise, an Azure SQL Table is a relatively simple way to store this info.  Then one sending Logic App can look up the details there.

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure, no other way to route EDI/X12 messages to trading partners without using Integration Account. Unless you create a Web API that will do the same  like parsing EDI/X12 headers and send it to trading partners.

Other way is to route your EDI to BizTalk via BizTalk Logic App Adapter and use BizTalk Parties EDI/X12 Agreement.

Comment: I may have not expressed the question all that well.  Our partners are not using EDI/X12.  They are using HL7, but we would like to use the integration account the same way as we would if they were using EDI/X12 so that we can manage our trading partners, their schemas, and identifiers all from the integration account dashboard.  It appears, however, that its only for partners that actually want to receive EDI/X12.  I'm just confirming that I cannot use an integration account to manage partners for all of our HL7 message exchanges if that makes any sense.